# SQL question about GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I've been using SQL for a few years, and this type of problem comes up here and there, and I haven't found an answer.  But perhaps I've been looking in the wrong places - I'm not really sure what to call it.

For the sake of brevity, let's say I have a table with 3 columns: Customer, Order_Amount, Order_Date.  Each customer may have multiple orders, with one row for each order with the amount and date.

My Question: Is there a simple way in SQL to get the DATE of the maximum order per customer?

I can get the amount of the maximum order for each customer (and which customer made it) by doing something like:

```
SELECT Customer, MAX(Order_Amount) FROM orders GROUP BY Customer;
```

But I also want to get the date of the max order, which I haven't figured out a way to easily get.  I would have thought that this would be a common type of question for a database, and would therefore be easy to do in SQL, but I haven't found an easy way to do it yet.  Once I add Order_Date to the list of columns to select, I need to add it to the Group By clause, which I don't think will give me what I want.

Comment: See (DBA.SE) http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1002/630

Comment: If a customer has two orders for the same amount which should be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from self-join you can do:

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM orders o1 JOIN orders o2 ON o1.Customer = o2.Customer
GROUP BY o1.Customer, o1.Order_Amount
HAVING o1.Order_Amount = MAX(o2.Order_Amount);
```

There's a good [article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/) reviewing various approaches.

And in Oracle, db2, Sybase, SQL Server 2005+ you would use [`RANK() OVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Order_Amount DESC) r
    FROM orders) o 
WHERE r = 1;
```

**Note**: If `Customer` has more than one order with maximum `Order_Amount` (i.e. ties), using `RANK()` function would get you all such orders; to get only first one, replace `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: RANK is in Oracle, db2, Sybase. And its only SQL 2005 and later.

Answer (score 2):

There's no short-cut... the easiest way is probably to join to a sub-query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders JOIN
    (
        SELECT Customer, MAX(Order_Amount) AS Max_Order_Amount
        FROM orders 
        GROUP BY Customer
    ) maxOrder 
        ON maxOrder.Customer = orders.Customer 
        AND maxOrder.Max_Order_Amount = orders.Order_Amount
```

Answer (score 2):

you will want to join on the same table...

```
SELECT Customer, order_date, amt 
FROM orders o,
    ( SELECT Customer, MAX(Order_Amount) amt FROM orders GROUP BY Customer ) o2
WHERE o.customer = o2.customer
AND o.order_amount = o2.amt
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for the collection:

```
WITH tempquery AS 
(
    SELECT 
         Customer
        ,Order_Amount
        ,Order_Date
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Order_Amount DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        orders 
)
SELECT 
     Customer
    ,Order_Amount
    ,Order_Date
FROM
    tempquery
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Comment: exactly what i was going to post, just couldn't get my thougths straightened out

Comment: This won't work because you're missing the `GROUP BY` Clause and you have a  `MAX(ORDER_DATE)` in there. You're probably better of just removing the column. Also the ORDER BY should be Order_Amount not Order_Date

Comment: Thanks Conrad - had misread the question, and introduced a typo.

Answer (score 1):

If your DB Supports CROSS APPLY you can do this as well, but it doesn't handle ties correctly

```
SELECT [....]
FROM Customer c
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 [...] 
 FROM Orders o
 WHERE c.customerID = o.CustomerID
 ORDER BY o.Order_Amount DESC) o
```

See this [data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1602/top-100-users-top-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT Customer, MAX(Order_Amount), Order_Date 
FROM orders  O
WHERE ORDER_AMOUNT = (SELECT MAX(ORDER_AMOUNT) FROM orders WHERE CUSTOMER = O.CUSTOMER)
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, Order_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 with t as
(
 select  CUSTOMER,Order_Date ,Order_Amount,max(Order_Amount) over (partition 
 by Customer) as
 max_amount from orders
)
select * from t  where t.Order_Amount=max_amount
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *why* this code solves the OP's problem.

Comment: When answering an older question with existing answers it helps to explain why your answer differs from existing answers. For example you could explain why your answer isn't the same as Martin's.